# Pytest issue with starting chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I have created 2 tests in 2 different .py files (languages_test, rating_tool), those 'test runs' use fixture function from conftest.py which is responsible for starting chromedriver and getting the page that's supposed to be tested.
The issue is that when I run my test as:
`pytest tests/dashboard/rating_tool.py` - everything works
But when I cd to *tests* folder and run same command without *tests* in path I get an error that chromedriver crashed and it couldnt launch properly.
My problems images:

1. [Error that I get when I cd to tests folder and run pytest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Co2.png)
2. [Options in my conftest - driver is located in tests folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDe9W.png)

I want my tests to run from test_runner.py but when trying that I have discovered this issue so I think that this needs to be resolved first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binary_location = './chromedriver'` means the binary will be looked up relative to the current working directory. That makes it extremely brittle as any change of current working directory will break its lookup.

You need to create the path to the binary based on [the `rootdir` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.Config.rootpath), whose base [normally resolves to the location of the nearest pytest.ini or pyproject.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/customize.html#finding-the-rootdir)

Comment: I have added pytest.ini file, and is it okay to define path to chromedriver inside that .ini file and then use it in conftest?

Comment: You can add whatever you want in your ini file. You can also use `pytest_addoption` to add command-line options to pytest, then pass it explicitely or use `addopts` in the ini file.

Comment: I'm sorry if Im asking stupid question but, this puzzles me a litle bit I have added chromedriver_path=./chromedriver to pytest.ini, and when I try to get that inside conftest.py with request.config.chromedriver_path - I receive error: AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'chromedriver_path'.
So basically I have everything in root of /tests folder as on image in question: pytest.ini, conftest and chromedriver are all inside /tests fodler.

Comment: That you add stuff to the ini file does not mean *pytest* will parse them, it just means they're in the ini file and you can parse them yourself by reloading the config file (`pytestconfig.inifile`) using `ConfigParser` and reading whatever bits you want. For pytest to read your option, you also need to tell pytest about it using [`addini`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.Parser.addini) and even then I doubt pytest will add it to its internal config object, which is for pytest's own stuff.